# Firefox: remove line around table cell

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a simple table which allows the user some interactions using the ctrl key.

Everything works fine but on FF, when the the user holds the ctrl and clicks a cell (`<td>`) a blue line is added:

[image]

I tried removing it using `outline: 0;` but with no success.

**scss:**

```
table {
        border-top: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
        th {
            min-width: 150px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        th,
        td {   
            border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
            vertical-align: middle;
            outline: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you use bootstrap; then you should make -   td:focus{ outline: none !important; }

Comment: @bfahmi - where in my code do you see bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
table { -moz-user-select: none; }
```

If the above doesn't workt then try this:

$('table').on('mousedown', function(e) {
 if (e.ctrlKey) { e.preventDefault(); } });